# Adding JOIN to nested Select in MySQL

Tags: mysql

To the query below, I would like the ability to display in the final result the full player name of each player selected in the nested Select. I know how to concatenate the appropriate fields: `CONCAT (nameFirst, ' ', nameLAST) AS 'playerName'` and where to put that in the first `SELECT`. Both nameFirst and nameLast are in the Master table. The key field `playerID` is in both the Batting and Master table. What I do not know is what I need to add to the query below to get the full names to appear for each Met who hit the most homers in a specific season.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Batting b JOIN
     (SELECT yearID, teamID, MAX(HR) as maxHR
      FROM Batting
      WHERE teamID = 'NYN'
      GROUP BY yearID, teamId
     ) bb
     ON bb.yearId = b.yearId and bb.teamId = b.teamId and bb.maxHR = b.HR;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you post a sample of input rows from the `Batting` table together with a sample of what the query's desired output should be, given that input rowset.

Answer (score 0):

The join should be an INNER JOIN to ensure you only select the record with the max(HR) - if there are multiple players with the same max(HR) they will both appear. Then you should LEFT JOIN the Master table to get the names of the players:

```
SELECT b.*, CONCAT (m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLAST)
  FROM Batting b 
  INNER JOIN
     (SELECT yearID, teamID, MAX(HR) as maxHR
        FROM Batting
        WHERE b.teamID = 'NYN'
       GROUP BY yearID, teamId
     ) bb
    ON bb.yearId = b.yearId 
       and bb.teamId = b.teamId 
       and bb.maxHR = b.HR
   LEFT JOIN Master m
    ON b.playerID = m.playerID
   ORDER BY b.yearID desc;
```

Comment: econnormist, your response works perfectly. I'll have to study it to fully appreciate what you did, so might be asking some questions about it later. Thank you very much. BTW, without the "WHERE teamID='NYN' line I would get the home run leaders for every MLB team. I just want the home run leaders for the New York Mets.

Comment: Cool - then you can have a simpler sub-query. I'll update the answer - appreciated if you flag as correct!

Comment: econnormist, why did you relocate WHERE teamID = 'NYN' from just after "From Batting" to the bottom of the query? What difference does that make?

Comment: It makes no difference to the output - just for neatness.

Comment: It changed the output. The home run values are no longer correct, and the years are no longer in ascending order. Here's a sample of the results now: playerID yearID stint teamID lgID G G_batting AB R H 2B 3B HR RBI SB CS BB SO IBB HBP SH SF GIDP G_old CONCAT (m.nameFirst, ' ', m.nameLAST)
hickmji02 1963 1 NYN NL 146 NULL 494 53 113 21 6 17 51 0 5 44 120 1 1 3 4 8 NULL Jim Hickman
davisto02 1967 1 NYN NL 154 NULL 577 72 174 32 0 16 73 9 3 31 71 10 7 1 5 16 NULL Tommy Davis
charled01 1968 1 NYN NL 117 NULL 369 41 102 11 1 15 53 5 4 28 57 4 2 6 4 7 NULL Ed Charles

Comment: Hard to say why without access to the data - I've edited it back inside the subquery and specified the order by clause.

Comment: FYI, the data is available for free [here](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/).